# Compiler acts as if a preprocessor directive isn't defined

Tags: c++

I have a header file and its cpp file (Error.h, Error.cpp). The cpp file performs a check on a preprocessor directive but it always fails.

Error.h:

```
/*
Optional macros:
AE_EXIT_AT_ERROR
AE_CONSOLE_WRITE_AT_ERROR
*/
#pragma once

extern void aeError(const char *str, int code=1);

extern void aeAssert(bool b, const char *failStr = "assertion failed");
```

Error.cpp:

```
#include "Error.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#ifdef AE_CONSOLE_WRITE_AT_ERROR
#include <iostream>
#endif

void aeError(const char *str, int code)
{
    #ifdef AE_CONSOLE_WRITE_AT_ERROR
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    #endif

    throw std::runtime_error(str);

    #ifdef AE_EXIT_AT_ERROR
    std::exit(code);
    #endif
}

void aeAssert(bool b, const char *failStr)
{
    if(!b)
        aeError(failStr);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
//define both macros:
#define AE_CONSOLE_WRITE_AT_ERROR
#define AE_EXIT_AT_ERROR
#include "Error.h"

//rest of code
//...
```

both `std::cout << str << std::endl;` and `std::exit(code);` don't get compiled (I checked it "manually", although they are also marked gray by the IDE, which is VS2010).

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: The exit after your throw will never be executed.

Comment: Why? It should be executed after the runtime error. (I think I can choose to "continue" in the message window that pops up)

Comment: After the `throw` statement, the function exits. Anything else is non-standard behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`main.cpp` and `Error.cpp` are different translation units. You define the macro only for `main.cpp`, not for `Error.cpp`.

You should either put your `#define` directives in a header file included by both .cpp files, or define these macros in project settings/makefile.